# create Document from Template, then use that Document inside MailMerge Event

Tags: vba, ms-word

What is the best way within a MailMerge Application Event to access a `Document` object which has been created by opening a macro-enabled template?

More specifically, I'm writing code for a macro-enabled template **Template.dotm**. When that template is opened, it creates a new document, usually called **Document1**, with a reference to **Template.dotm**.

Here's the `ThisDocument` module of **Template.dotm**.

```
Dim objEventHandler As clsEventHandler

Private Sub Document_New()
  Set objEventHandler = New clsEventHandler
  Set objEventHandler.AppWithEvents = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Close()
  Set objEventHandler = Nothing
End Sub
```

And here's my event handler class.

```
Public WithEvents AppWithEvents As Word.Application

Private Sub AppWithEvents_MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
  'code needs to reference "Document1"
End Sub
```

Within the `MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge` procedure, I want to access **Document1**. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268676/word-vba-events-only-fire-once-for-documents-based-on-a-template) comes close to addressing this, but not quite.

What doesn't work:

- `ThisDocument` refers to **Template.dotm**.
- `ActiveDocument` refers to the mailmerge result file.
- `ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate` might be the way to go, but I haven't figure out how to resolve a `Document` object from a `Template` object.
- In a pinch, I might loop through open documents and identify it by filename, but I don't know what other documents a user may have open when this is run, so I'd prefer a less breakable strategy.

Many, many thanks for any advice.

Comment: So you're not trying to reference the Mail Merge Main document, i.e. using the parameter Doc? Document1 may be a different document altogether?

Comment: Wow. That was embarassingly right in front of my nose. You are correct: `Doc` is **Document1**.